# Install Bluestacks on Compaq Presario CQ40 windows 8 32bit

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, android, bluestacks, compaq-laptop

I always get this error,

"Your graphics hardware or driver do not support apps that needs high performance graphics. A limited version is being installed, some apps may not run. You may update the graphics drivers and re-install Bluestacks to try to resolve this limitation"

But I already update my graphics driver to its latest version,
Name    : Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
Version : 7.15.10.1502

Comment: according to the Bluestacks help forums, the current intel driver is not compatible and you need to downgrade your driver or try to use the one linked to in the answer here https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/_fix_intel_video_drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bluestacks help forums, the current Intel driver is not compatible and you need to downgrade your driver or try to use the driver linked to in the answer [by Charlie B on Bluestacks forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/_fix_intel_video_drivers).

> If you have an Intel video chipset, you may need a third party
>   replacement driver, especially in Windows 8.
>
> If you have one of the following chipsets:
>
> - Intel(R) B43 Express Chipset
> - Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset
> - Intel(R) G43 Express Chipset
> - Intel(R) G45 Express Chipset
> - Intel(R) Q43 Express Chipset
> - Intel(R) Q45 Express Chipset
> - Mobile Intel(R) GL40 Express Chipset
> - Mobile Intel(R) GM45 Express Chipset
> - Mobile Intel(R) GS45 Express Chipset
>
> Download one of the following for your system:
>
> ---
>
> 32bit Video Driver: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68552889/ROYAL.BNA.DRIVER.V3.1-SNiPER%5BBNA%5D%E2%84%A2.rar
>
> 64bit Video Driver: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68552889/ROYAL.BNA.DRIVER.3.1.64-SNiPER%5BBNA%5D%E2%84%A2.zip
>
> ---
>
> Installation
>
> 1. Run `cmd.exe` as administrator by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd.exe`
> 2. Type the following two commands, line by line, or copy/paste them one
>      at a time
>
>    ```
>    bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
>    bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
>    ```
> 3. Reboot and install BNA by unzipping the file you downloaded above and
>      running `RBNADSetup.exe`.
> 4. After install, reboot, run a command prompt again and enter
>
>    ```
>    bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
>    bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
>    ```
> 5. Reboot again
> 6. Try your install now